# Boost::Regex usage in C++

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I got this regex and I'd like to ask if I am using it correctly

```
regex re("(\\S+)=[\"']?((?:.(?![\"']?\\s+(?:\\S+)=|[>\"']))+.)[\"']?",regex::extended,regex::icase);
       while (getline(input, temp, '>')) {
            parse+=temp;
            bool isMatchFound = regex_match(parse, match, re);

            if(isMatchFound){
            //Do something
            }
        }
```

It should match `<a href="bla.html"></a>` tags and `match[2]` should be `bla.html`

It throws this exception:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::regex_error> >'
  what():  Invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition operator.  The error occurred while parsing the regular expression fragment: 'ed_state**>>>HERE>>>, boost::r
```

Comment: I would use regex_search instead. `boost::smatch match; if (regex_search(parse, match, re) { string str1 = match[1].str(); string str2 = match[2].str(); }`. Also, use perl mode instead of extended.

Comment: @sln perl mode includes icase? or should I just use perl mode and icase too ?

Comment: There is nothing in your regex that needs case insensitivity. I didn't include them in my defines because I could always add `(?i)` to the regex on a case by case basis. Look in the includes to find `icase`, then add the `i` permutations (ie. MODi,MODxi, etc..). Just OR it into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think extended is going to cut it for assertions. Best to use Perl mode.
I just tested your regex with your options, it does the same for me.

I would use one of these defines (specifically MODs or MODxs).
I used MODxs and it didn't throw an error on startup.

```
 #define MOD    regex_constants::perl | boost::regex::no_mod_s | boost::regex::no_mod_m 
 #define MODx   regex_constants::perl | boost::regex::no_mod_s | boost::regex::no_mod_m | regex_constants::mod_x
 #define MODs   regex_constants::perl | boost::regex::no_mod_m | regex_constants::mod_s
 #define MODxs  regex_constants::perl | boost::regex::no_mod_m | regex_constants::mod_s | regex_constants::mod_x

 #define MODm   regex_constants::perl | boost::regex::no_mod_s  
 #define MODxm  regex_constants::perl | boost::regex::no_mod_s| regex_constants::mod_x
 #define MODsm  regex_constants::perl | regex_constants::mod_s
 #define MODxsm regex_constants::perl | regex_constants::mod_s | regex_constants::mod_x


 boost::regex  rx( "(\\S+)=[\"']?((?:.(?![\"']?\\s+(?:\\S+)=|[>\"']))+.)[\"']?", MODxs );   // or MODs
```